# using values from a query in another query

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comprofiler WHERE cb_playstationgames LIKE '%FIFA%' ORDER BY id ASC");
```

in that query there is a user_id wich i need to perform a query on another table.

```
$gebruikerid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where id LIKE '".$result['user_id']."'");
```

Now i want to use that value in a while loop

```
echo "<table><tr><th width=\"300\" align=\"left\" >Avatar</th><th width=\"300\" align=\"left\">Naam</th><th width=\"200\" align=\"left\">PSN Naam</th></tr>"; 

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<tr><td><img height=\"50\" width=\"50\" src=\"/images/comprofiler/" . $row2['avatar'] . "\"></td><td>" . $gebruikernaam . "</td><td>" .     $row2['cb_psnnaam'] . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I cannot get the query to read the values from the other table based on the id from the first table. Can someone help me?

Comment: What does not work? Or what "does not work" mean? Or who is "does not work"?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You should MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements, mysql_ functions have been deprecated.

Comment: You didn't fetch the second query `gebruikernaam `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the best solution it's to use JOIN.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT comprofiler.*, users.* FROM comprofiler INNER JOIN users ON users.id = comprofiler.user_id WHERE cb_playstationgames LIKE '%FIFA%' ORDER BY comprofiler.id ASC");
```

You may have to manually specify the columns you want to select (after SELECT ) in case that you have same column names in both table and you need both.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT comprofiler.id as id_comprofiler, users.id as id_user, users.avatar ... " );
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question why it does not work:

```
Second query does not use mysql_fetch_array.
$gebruikerid = mysql_fetch_array($gebruikerid);
```

It would be more **secure** & **cleaner** if you would use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or MySQLi prepared statements like:

```
$db     = new \PDO(SEE PDO CUNSTRUCT)
$query1 = $db->prepare('
            SELECT * 
            FROM comprofiler 
            WHERE cb_playstationgames LIKE :fifa 
            ORDER BY id ASC
          ');

$query2 = $db->prepare('
             SELECT * FROM users where id LIKE :id
          ');

$query1->bindValue(':fifa', '%FIFA%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query1->execute();

while ($row = $query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $query2->bindParam(':id', $row['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $query2->execute();

   //Holds associative array of second query
   $row2 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

   //$row1 holds associative array of first query
}
```